# SQL Server - Pass image to stored procedure, invalid local var type

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I have two tables that contain document content: one for temporary staging, other for permanent storage. The content is stored as type image (cannot change this since it's current functionality).

I need a stored procedure that does the following:

1. Pass in a TempDocumentID that exists in temp document table.
2. With that TempDocumentID, select image content from temp document table.
3. Exec existing stored procedure that takes an image parameter to insert into permanent document table.

My problem is two-fold:

- I can't declare a local variable of type 'image' to fill from the select statement of temp table. It throws error 'The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables.'
- I don't know of a way to exec stored proc with direct results from select statement of temp table.

Here is my SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09384/5

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it doesn't get an error in SQL Fiddle.  I believe it will pass the result from the sub-query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MoveDocumentFromTemp
(
  @TempDocumentID numeric(18,0)
)
AS
BEGIN

  EXEC InsertDocumentContentFinal (SELECT TempContent
  FROM DocumentContentTemp (NOLOCK)
  WHERE TempDocumentID = @TempDocumentID)
END
```

Comment: That works, but it doesn't check for that actual stored proc. I edited the fiddle to contain both procs and an exec statement that should actually do what I need to do. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a89ac/3

Comment: Ahh darn, yeah I don't think the sub-query as a parameter will work... RichardTheKiwi's answer might work better.  Sorry.  Just took a stab in the dark with that answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use VARBINARY(MAX) with SQL Server 2005 and later.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MoveDocumentFromTemp
(
  @TempDocumentID numeric(18,0)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ContentToMove varbinary(max)
  SELECT @ContentToMove = cast(TempContent as varbinary(max))
  FROM DocumentContentTemp (NOLOCK)
  WHERE TempDocumentID = @TempDocumentID

  EXEC InsertDocumentContentFinal @ContentToMove
END
GO
```

For SQL Server 2000, you'll just have to include the INSERT code from MoveDocumentFromTemp directly into your wrapper stored procedure.

Comment: Our clients are running SQL Server 2000 so this won't work (as much as I'd love it to).

Comment: then you're out of luck AFAIK